# How to test (true/false) for mobile IE ONLY on Windows Phone 7 or greater in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, user-agent

How to test (true/false) for mobile IE, or Edge, ONLY on Windows Phone 7 or greater Windows Phone (incl. 8.1, 10, etc.), in JavaScript, but not catch Chrome, Firefox, or nor any other mobile (not even Mobile Chrome, if it should appear in Windows 10 Phone Store), nor desktop browsers (Not even desktop IE or Edge)?

Plain vanilla JavaScript. Please, No jQuery.

I have:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)) 
    {
        var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
        msViewportStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode("@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}"));
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
    };
```

But I know it won't work, properly.

Comment: Instead of `match` use `test` method that returns a boolean. `if(/Windows Phone/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    // code
}`

Comment: But what if Chrome joins the Windows 10 Phone store. My if statement only checks the OS presence, not specifically for IE or Edge.

Comment: Never test for a browser - it's more than a full-time job and the tools at your disposal (`navigator.xxx`) are unreliable. Instead, ask yourself what feature of the API you want to use and test for that feature.

Comment: I'm curious: why do you want to test for that combination? Why does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function :

```
function checkBrowser(){
 var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
 var res=false;
 if(userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)){
  if(userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")!=-1 || userAgent.indexOf("Edge")!=-1 || userAgent.indexOf("IEMobile")!=-1){
  res=true;
  }
 }
return res;
}
```

You can add more checks, if any missed, in inner if block.

Comment: `navigator.userAgent` is unreliable.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, Can you please tell what else we can use for detecting browsers? If we have to perform some browser specific functionality then what we do? Please share your thoughts with proper explanation. One line statement  is not going to help any body and not even solve the purpose of StackOverflow.

Comment: Calm down Scott. I'm not looking to reinvent the wheel. Just a simple function or if statement. As long as it gets mobile IE or Edge 99% of the time while ignoring others, that's perfectly fine with me.

Comment: We haven't done "browser detection" since the early 2000's because of the fact that it is not a tenable goal and the fact that there really isn't a fool-proof way to do it. Instead, forget about what browser the user has and focus on what aspect of the API you want to use and test for the feature, not the browser. (i.e. `if(window.addEventListener)` is a way to test to see if the browser implements the `addEventListener()` method - it doesn't matter that in reality, if it doesn't we must be talking about IE 8 or less).

Comment: @JamesAndersonJr. I'm not excited. I'm giving you the correct answer. Sorry if you don't like it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, I agree with you on that point, but what if I have to show an image depending on browser. How will I achieve that?

Comment: Test for an API that is unique to that browser, not the browser type itself. For example, if I had to detect whether a user was using IE 8 or less, I would write `if(window.attachEvent){}` because that is an API that is only supported in those browsers. There is no way for the browser to fake that answer. User Agent strings can (and are) easily spoofed.

Comment: You mean for each and every browser we should create a unique API or different libraries but still the question is how we can invoke that a specific API that is unique to a browser? In any case we have to identify browser.

Comment: No, you don't create an API. You are testing for the existence of an API ("feature"). See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273397(v=vs.85).aspx or https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/feature-browser-detection/ for some background.